# SQL Server : query to update a table by using join on a column which has duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here I am trying to take values from `Table2` and updating into `Table1`. I am joining on `Id3`.

What I want is to add one more condition such that, if `Id4` is present in `Table2` then it should be matched to that in `Table1` and that row should be used for updating.

In case `Id4` doesn't match, the update should still happen depending on `Id3`.

```
Update w 
set w.id1 = s.Id1, w.id2 = s.id2 
from Table1 w 
join Table2 s on w.id3 = s. id3 
where w.id1 is null
```

I have reframed the above query below to use a condition on `Id4`, but it is not working properly as it is still taking random duplicate rows.

```
Update w 
set w.id1 = s.Id1, w.id2 = s.id2 
from Table1 w 
join Table2 s on w.id3 = s. id3 
where w. id1 is null 
  and (w. id4 = s.id4 or (1=1))
```

Can someone reframe a better query then above?

Comment: Please show us data in tabular form which explains the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, because your input is a bit unclear, but maybe you can try this, in two steps:

```
UPDATE Table W Set Id1 = S.Id1 FROM Table1 AS W
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Table2 AS S 
               WHERE S.Id4 = W.Id4 )
```

Step two:

```
UPDATE Table W Set Id1 = S.Id1 FROM Table1 AS W
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM Table2 AS S 
               WHERE S.Id3 = W.Id3 )
  AND ISNULL (Id1, '') = ''
```

Comment: see table2 has duplicate values... so if i use id3 as joining condition then it is randomly taking the first row. 
now thing is if id4 matches (in addition to id3 which is mandatory to match)  then that column should be used for updating.

your methid wont help me as i dint want id4 to be directly updated.... 
anything you can suggest in one query??

Comment: i mean,  here in the first query you are assuming thaat if id4 matches then just update.. that will create huge problem as id4 column has too manh dupes

Comment: I'm sorry. I just don't follow your logic. Seems fine to me. Please add sample data and output in format that you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Quetion is little bit unclear. Try this:

```
Update w set w.id1 = s.Id1, w.id2=s.id2 
from Table1 w join Table2 s 
on w.id3 = s.id3 or w.id4 = s.id4
```